# Rails 3 customize validate's error with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-i18n

I'm using some validates on my model and try to convert error to my language

Here in my Model `TaiSan` I have some validates like this:

```
class TaiSan < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :MaTS, :TenTS
 validates_length_of :MaTS, :in => 9..10, :allow_nil => false
 validates_presence_of :MaTS
 validates_uniqueness_of :MaTS
```

In Controller and View I just leave at it be as default (scafford)

And in my `locales\vi.yml` look like this

```
vi:
 errors: &errors
   format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
 messages:
   taken: đã tồn tại trong cơ sở dữ liệu
   blank: không được trống
   empty: không được rỗng
   too_long:
    one: quá dài (tối đa là 1 kí tự)
    other: quá dài (tối đa là %{count} kí tự)
   too_short:
    one: quá ngắn (tối thiểu là 1 kí tự)
    other: quá ngắn (tối thiểu là %{count} kí tự)
   wrong_length:
    one: sai độ dài (phải là 1 kí tự)
    other: sai độ dài (phải là %{count} kí tự)
```

Any others except of validate_uniqueness_of's error message work fine, which was translated to my language defined above, but with `taken:` is still is `'...has already been taken'`

Any clues what's I missed ??? Very precious to any hints and answer

**Solution**

I've added some code after `vi:` in `locale\vi.yml` like this:

```
vi:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
       taken: "đã tồn tại"
```

Now It works fine !!! So why is it which I have to add `activerecord` before uniqueness validation but other ( presence, length, ... ) is dont need ????

Answer (score 0):

Rails already comes with a lot of different language translations built in, in the `rails-i18n` gem. This includes Vietnamese.

Anyway... when writing custom validation messages, make sure you specify the right nested keys.

Your translation file should follow the same YAML format as the default, eg:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/vi.yml

So the full key for the `taken` translation would be `vi.errors.messages.taken`, not `en.messages.taken`.

Note that your language should also be specified in the YAML file as `vi`, not `en`.

Comment: thks for quick response, about `vi` and `en`'s problem, due to my copy-paste, sry my bad, it's `vi` in there and it's still wrong at unique attribute

Comment: I looked more into your link and found a solution which was edited above, can you tell me what difference, i'm confusing in there, thks in advance

Comment: again, you need to nest your keys correctly. You don't have to nest them under `activerecord`, but you do need to nest them under `errors`.

Comment: Sry for not make things clear to you, as I mentioned b4, the problem you said about is my mistake when posting this question (length or presence's validation worked fine, though). I nested like you said: `errors: > messages: > taken:` but it didn't work until I nest them on `activerecord`